# How to access PDO database connection object in another class in php?

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO in my project, So My PDO connection with database was made successfully but when I access the PDO object in another class system encountered error like following

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string

Following is my database connection class

```
class DBConnect
{
    public static function getDB()
    {

        try {

                $dsn    = DTConfig::dbtype.":host=".DTConfig::host.";dbname=".DTConfig::db;
                $user   = DTConfig::user;
                $dbname = DTConfig::password;

                $db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$dbname);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }   

        return $db;     
    }
}
```

In following code I want to access the PDO object but I got error like "Object of class PDO could not be converted to string on line 5"

```
class Administrator{

    function __construct(){

         $db = DBConnect::getDB(); //line 5 - This is not working 
         //echo $db;die;
    }
```

Anybody please suggest me answer
Thanks in advance

Comment: Was the `echo $db;` _uncommented_ when the error occured, because an instance should be `var_dump`-ed at least

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, when I try to echo the PDO object I get the same error.

Replace

```
echo $db;
```

with:

```
var_dump($db);
```

Comment: I am not trying to print the object $db.I want to access the PDO object in administrator class

Comment: Nevertheless this is the only line in the above code that could cause this error